# Decimals in Apex: setting scale without rounding

Tags: apex, decimal

Is there a possible way to set the scale of a decimal in Apex wihtout applying any rounding?
(FI, the method setScale of Decimal object apply by default a half even rounding)

Example: the following statment displays 0.46 instead of the non rounded value 0.45:

`system.debug('#Decimal:'+(0.4579060401674421859641886792928).setscale(2));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of different rounding modes that you can specify for decimal, these are described here. ([Rounding modes](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_methods_system_decimal.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp))

I don't think any of them give the result you are looking for, which seems to be to ignore the figures after the second decimal place.

You could achieve that result using String methods to truncate the source value like this

```
String myNumber = '0.4579060401674421859641886792928';
String myTruncatedNumber = myNumber.subString(0,myNumber.indexOf('.')+3);
Decimal d = Decimal.valueOf(myTruncatedNumber);
System.debug(d);
```

Here, the String methods discard the trailing information that you are not interested and then when it is converted to a decimal it takes the precision from the remaining String (2 decimal places). This gives the output 0.45

Comment: Thanks @DougB for the reply, I was looking for a clean way to do this (without casting/formatting strings) but I don't see another solution other than using strings

Comment: @Marone - it's a shame there isn't a rounding mode to do it the way you want, but I think you're stuck with the casting/formatting approach. Unless you can cleanse the data before it reaches your class...

Answer (score 4):

Well there are more methods available @ Decimal class.
You can try specifying the ROUNDING MODE by doing something like this

```
system.debug('#Decimal:'+(0.4579060401674421859641886792928).setscale(2,RoundingMode.DOWN));
```

For example
The Down Rounding mode always rounds towards zero, you can select other rounding modes from http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm#apex_decimal_rounding_mode

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using Rounding Modes. For example

```
decimal dec = 23.5678;
System.debug('Decimal Value after scale '+dec.setscale(2,system.RoundingMode.DOWN));
```

Console Output: Decimal Value after scale 23.56